# why wait() return -1 on xcode Version 7.2.1 (7C1002)

Tags: xcode, macos, fork, wait, errno

guys, I have the following c code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>


int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int exit;
    pid_t tc_pid, ret_pid;
    tc_pid = fork();
    if(tc_pid != 0){
        ret_pid = wait(&exit);
        printf("parent process done, tc_pid = %d, ret_pid = %d, errno = %d\n", tc_pid, ret_pid, errno);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    printf("parent process done, tcpid = %d, my_pid = %d\n", tc_pid, getpid());
    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```

the output on xcode is:

```
parent process done, tcpid = 0, my_pid = 74377
parent process done, tc_pid = 74377, ret_pid = -1, errno = 4
parent process done, tcpid = 74377, my_pid = 74374
```

where here the return value of wait() is -1(should be 74377 if correct), and errno is -4

However, when I use the same code run in terminal(I use zsh), the output is:

```
parent process done, tcpid = 0, my_pid = 74419
parent process done, tc_pid = 74419, ret_pid = 74419, errno = 0
parent process done, tcpid = 74419, my_pid = 74418
```

which is what I want. Does anyone knows why would this happen? Thanks guys.

my OSX is 10.11.3 and my machine is MBPR early 2015, xcode 7.2.1,
gcc 4.2.1, Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81), Target: x86_64-apple-darwin15.3.0, Thread model: posix

Answer (score 0):

According to `errno.h`, errno of `4` is `EINTR` which the [man page for `wait` says is](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man2/wait.2.html):

`The call is interrupted by a caught signal or the signal does not have the SA_RESTART flag set.`

You apparently are using a signal to get `wait` to exit.  Perhaps you might need to rethink what are you ultimately trying to do here, and is there a way to do it without using `wait`?

Comment: Hi, Michael, thanks for the reply, I just want to see how fork() works and how wait() works. The question is in gcc the output is correct while in xcode isn't, why does this happen, the xcode send an interrupt signal to process?